# How does shadow magic work when its reality exceeds 100%?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Dungeons & Dragons is about fantasy. Things that happen in the game aren't real, we only pretend that they are. For example, [shadow conjuration](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/shadowConjuration.htm)s "are actually one-fifth (20%) as strong as the real things". However, there are ways of "enrealening" them, such as the Enhanced Shadow Reality feat (Dragon Magazine #325), the Shadowcrafter prestige class (Underdark, p.43), and turning to [the dark side](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/planes.htm#planeOfShadow).

Next thing you know, the [shadow](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#shadow) magic is over 100%! Things just got real... too real. How do they work then?

Answer (score 7):

There is something philosophical, no doubt, in the fact that this hinges on your definition of "reality."

There is no rule that limits this percentage to unity (100%), and all of the mathematical operations in which it is used work fine with percentages above it. So from that end, realer than real could be a thing.

The question, then, is whether "reality" is a game-term, defined exclusively by the rules of the (Shadow) spells, or not and defined as in real life. If the former, then realer-than-real spells are possible, and succeeding on a saving throw causes you to be *more* affected than failing. If the latter, it's a matter of what you think reality is; whether or not it has some essentially fake quality that something can be more real than it.

Strict RAW, it seems to be a game term, so your damaging spells deal more damage. Your non-damaging spells always work.

And it doesn't matter because every DM should ban reality-improving effects, particularly the shadowcraft mage, on sight. (Why? Because the spells are too versatile like that. It's basically spontaneously casting the entire Sor/Wiz list. Plus a shadowcraft mage [can be optimized](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?248346-Shadowcrafter-Mage#30) to cast *any* spell, from a cantrip (*silent image* used as *shadow evocation* for *miracle*).)

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something, but the shadowcraft mage's supernatural ability shadow illusion says that he "can use the altered spell to mimic any sorcerer or wizard conjuration (summoning), conjuration (creation), or evocation spell **at least one level lower than the illusion spell**" (*RS* 122) (emphasis mine). How does that equate to turning *silent images* into *miracles*?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Look up the killer gnome build for how to get from there to here.

Comment: Fair enough, although that was tougher to find than I would've liked. (With *Brilliant Gameologists* gone, the build stub is [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=19914066&postcount=41) and the explanation is [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?248346-Shadowcrafter-Mage#30).) Although this does seem more a problem with metamagic reducers—which are almost universally broken—than realer-than-real illusions.

Comment: @HeyICanChan It’s still one of the most formidable applications of metamagic reducers in existence, and that’s saying something. Spontaneous access to very nearly every spell ever is not something that happens automatically with metamagic reduction. And less than reality would be a serious flaw in this approach without shadowcraft mage.

Comment: Huh. Because a spell affected by the supernatural ability shadow spells "functions identically to the *shadow conjuration* or *shadow evocation* spell," wouldn't such an altered *silent image* inherit those spells' limitations? That is, wouldn't evocation school spells still be limited to Sor/Wiz spells of  4th-level and lower and conjuration and creation subschool spells still be limited to Sor/Wiz spells of 3rd-level and lower? Or have I missed something else? (Seriously, if you could point me at a thread at that addresses my concerns that'd be awesome, and I'll totally drop this.)

Comment: While I opened another thread on this issue (see Linked), I'm still curious how *silent image* used as *shadow evocation* becomes a *miracle* when [Heighten Spell](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#heighten-spell) says specifically that it's limited to heightening spells only up to 9th. Was that limitation overlooked, is there a way to overcome that limitation on Heighten Spell or shadow illusions, or is there a spell list that has as an 8th-level spell *miracle*?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Try looking up the killer gnome build for details; I’m reasonably sure the answer is that there is a way to overcome the limit, but to be sure you should double-check that.

Comment: @heyICanChan Earth Spell (RoS 138) explicitly changes how heighten spell functions and is a key part of that build. It’s unclear that it allows heightening to 10th, but that’s the most natural reading of the text (ie. you can heighten to 9, and earth spall makes that 10). I’m not defending that point, just presenting it.

Comment: @fectin Yeah, KRyan told me twice in this exchange to look up the killer gnome build, and I did, and the one I linked to didn't have the feat Earth Spell. The linked explanation of how it works relies on the feat, but, you're right: that is a reading that's difficult to defend, Heighten Spell explicitly limiting spells to a maximum of 9th-level and all.